# Computability: is there an alternative method to decide this language?

Tags: computer-science, computability, turing-machines

For my computability revision I am trying to decide the language, $$L = \{  \text{all binary strings containing the pattern 001 (not necessarily in consecutive places)} \}.$$

I believe that I can do this, however my method is very long and difficult to keep track of due to the many different states required for my Turing Machine.

Anyway, I proceeded as follows (exact details omitted):
Given an input string look for the first 0. Upon finding a zero, check if 001 occurs there. If so, accept and if not move to the next 0 then do the same. If at some point we see a blank then it means no 001 was seen so do a carriage return whereby we plan to test if 0•0•1 appears (• is any element in the alphabet).

I did this step in generality: suppose we want 0•••...•••0•••...•••1 where there are n•s in each case. Then, upon seeing a zero move along n places in the tape by defining new states at each symbol that act as a counter (see attached image). I know that I need to include details here regarding if a blank is seen because then we have reached the end of string => carriage return.

I'm fairly sure this algorithm is correct (with a bit of polishing) and since there are a lot (finitely many however) of states, then I am ok, but is there an easier method? For this algorthim I have initial, accept, reject, carriage return, find-0, find-1, move-n spaces (2sets, before and after middle 0 in the string! They are distinct) for each value of n between 1 and the length of the string: this is a nightmare to write and keep track of!

Surely an easier method exists?!

The image is only rough work so please don't be too cruel. Also, $x$ is any element in the input alphabet, there are special cases if we get to a blank.
[image: Method - iterative use of transition function]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: are there at least two $0$'s to the left of the rightmost $1$?

Comment: I see how this would work for the standard $001$ string, however, I don't see how this would solve the problem of deciding that 0#0#1 is in the language (for an arbitrary symbol #) because you still have to count the number of symbols between the first and second zero, then the second zero and first one. Do you think perhaps I am misunderstanding the question? My interpretation of it is that 001, 0#0#1, 0##0##1 etc should all be accepted.

Comment: Yes, I think you are misunderstanding.  The numbers of symbols between the 0, 0 and 1 don't have to be the same.  0#0##1, for example, is acceptable.

Comment: I think I understand now, thanks. Now that my misunderstanding is clarified I think your hint is particularly helpful too.

Answer (score 2):

Your language seems to correspond to the regular expression $1^*01^*01[01]^*$
You only need 3 states:

S1: "No zero encountered yet." If you read a 1, stay here, if you read a 0, go to state S2.

S2: "1 zero encountered." If you read a 1, stay here, if you read a 0, go to state S3.

S3: "2 or more zeros encountered." If you read a 0, stay here, if you read a 1 accept.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Firstly, what exactly do you mean by "the regular expression..."? Secondly, I understand how your states work (I have in fact written equivalent statements) but I fail to see how this deals with strings of 001 form but with separation between both zeros and the zero-one part.

Comment: A "regular expression" is a formal description of a language. A language that can be described like this is a "regular language" and can be accepted by a finite automaton, a less powerful computation model than a Turing machine.

Comment: If you encounter additional 1s before you have seen two zeros, or if you see more than two zeros before you reach the final 1, you just ignore these symbols and go on to read the next symbol.

Comment: I've just had my misinterpretation of the question clarified and now I understand what you are saying. Thanks for the help, it makes sense now!